# Отправить PIL Image на сервер через requests

Tags: python, requests, pillow

Имеется необходимость отправить изображение по методу PUT:

```
from PIL import Image

# качаем исходное изображение
response = requests.get('https://exemple.com/example.jpg', stream=True)
# создаём инстанс Image
main = Image.open(response.raw)
# накладываем WaterMark
main.paste(watermark, (x_offset, y_offset), watermark)
```

Теперь мне нужно это изображение по методу PUT отправить на Селектел:

```
url = 'http://......./что_то/тут/короче/путь_к_файлу'
headers = {
    'заголовки_для': 'авторизации'
}
response = requests.put(url, data=main, headers=headers)
```

Ругается вот так:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/AvitoParser$ python3 selectel_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "selectel_test.py", line 119, in <module>
    photo_proc(photo_url)
  File "selectel_test.py", line 84, in photo_proc
    response = requests.put(url, data=main, headers=headers)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 126, in put
    return request('put', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 494, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 437, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 308, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 505, in prepare_body
    self.prepare_content_length(body)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 516, in prepare_content_length
    length = super_len(body)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 145, in super_len
    o.seek(0, 2)
TypeError: seek() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Вариант с предварительным сохранением файла на диск я держу в уме, но не хотелось бы. Ибо если файл уже в памяти, смысла сохранять на диск, чтобы потом обратно читать и отправлять -- нет?

Как мне, собственно, получить из инстанса Image сам контент для отправки его через PUT на селектел?

P.S. Именно такой способ взаимодействия с requests (без словаря files) мне написали в техподдержке самого Селектела

Answer (score 1):

Удалось сделать так:

```
import io

raw_image = io.BytesIO()
main.save(raw_image, format='JPEG')
response = requests.put(url, data=raw_image.getvalue(), headers=headers)
```